# Public method with methods defined inside vs. private

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Suppose I have

```
class SomeClass
  def some_public_method
    method_1
    method_2
  end
```

where `method_1` and `method_2` won't be used by anything except `some_public_method`.

They can be defined inside that method:

```
class SomeClass
  def some_public_method
    def method_1
      p 'hi'
    end
    def method_2
      p 'there'
    end
    method_1
    method_2
  end
end
```

or defined separately as private ones in the class. I was wondering which approach will be easier to maintain in the future and why (should these methods "belong" to some_public_method and not created unless some_public_method is created or they should belong to the class). I think this question isn't opinion-based because of the why part. Please provide examples of how some other code might conflict with either of these two approaches to prove your point on why either approach is better for more maintainable code.

Comment: `some_other_method_1` and `some_other_methods_2`? Do you mean `method_1` and `method_2`?

Comment: The major why here seems to be why would you do this? You could privatize or modularize these methods. Once you call the main method `some_public_method` these methods will be defined as instance methods and will be accessible to the instance and will in no way be private. Can you explain you reason for wanting to do this because otherwise I don't think it is a valid SO question.

Comment: "Once you call the main method `some_public_method` these methods will be defined as instance methods" … and once you call `some_public_method` a second time, these methods will be defined *again* as instance methods, triggering a "method redefined" warning … and again … and again …

Comment: @JörgWMittag , that totally makes sense, can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? None of the answers so far answered this question as yours.

Comment: @engineersmnky because these methods won't be used outside of the class, and there will be only 1 public method that is going to use them. So far Jorg Mittag answer makes only sense on why this approach isn't good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such a thing as nested methods in ruby, but you can write methods which define new methods. By doing this:

```
class SomeClass
  def some_public_method
    def method_1
      p 'hi'
    end

    def method_2
      p 'there'
    end

    method_1
    method_2
  end

end
```

Methods `method_1` and `method2` are not defined just after class is declared, because their definitions has not been executed. As soon as you execute `some_public_method`, those definitions are executed and both methods are added to the class. Whether they are public or private depends on whether methods `private`, `protected` or `public` (Yep, those are methods) has been executed against the class or not. If none of those methods has been executed, they are public.

```
s = SomeClass.new
t = SomeClass.new

s.method_1     #=> undefined method error
t.some_public_method
s.method_1     #=> hi
```

If you run `some_public_method` again, those methods will be redefined which may result in a warning.

In short, do not nest method definitions, unless you are going for some nice metaprograming feature. Even then it is probably better to use `define_method` method.

Comment: I know that these methods won't be executed if some_public_method isn't first. My question was from a design perspective, whether it's best to "nest" them (not literally), or have them defined separately. How this all worked wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: @daremkd - It is - nesting them does not make them private in any way, they can still be executed anywhere by anything - hence nesting should be avoided except for few vary rare cases.

Comment: Clear and complete answer.  Nice!

Comment: The second version is both dangerous and annoying. It is dangerous, because it looks like a nested method, when in fact it is not. And it is annoying, because `method1` and `method2` will be re-defined over and over and over and over again everytime `some_public_method` is executed, which will generate gazillions of "method redefined" warnings … you *do* run your code with warnings enabled, don't you?

Comment: @JörgWMittag is there I way I can get in touch with you? Do you have an email, skype, anything?